# Dsharp+ custom choice to multiply 2 numbers

Tags: dsharp+

First time working with discord bots properly. I can't figure out how to implement custom choices for a user to input 2 numbers to multiply them together using slash commands.

i've tried to use the option attribute however that only lets me use pre-selected choices, i want the bot to be able to take any 2 numbers and multiply them